# Is the relation $R = \{a,b\}$ transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I was studying relations and functions and transitive relations were defined as :

$$R=\{(x,y)\} ; xRy ~\text{and}~ yRz \implies xRz$$

But what about a single element $(a,b)$?

For example, if the relation was

$$R = \{(1,2),(2,1),(1,1),(2,2)\}$$

Then clearly, it is transitive, but if the relation were :
$$R = \{(1,2),(2,1),(1,1),(2,2),(5,6)\}$$

Or simply :

$$R=\{(5,6)\}$$

Then are these relations transitive ?

Comment: You might want to change the question in the title to the one actually being asked. (First and foremost, replace "set" by "relation".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, that's transitive! For every triple of elements $a, b, c$, if $aRb$ and $bRc$ then $aRc$. It doesn't matter that there are some elements - namely, $5$ and $6$ - which can't be "extended" to form a triple. There's no more to transitivity than the definition you wrote above.

Comment: Then what is '$c$' here ( in my example)? Is it defined to be transitive or there is any explanation?

Comment: @JaideepKhare You're misunderstanding the definition. The definition just says *whenever you have* such a triple $a, b, c$, then [stuff]. It doesn't say that every element is *part* of some triple. The only way a relation $S$ is non-transitive is if there are three elements $a, b, c$ with $aSb$, $bSc$, but not $aSc$ - can you find such a triple of elements in this case?

Comment: Oh, now I understand, I think I misunderstood 'if ...(..)' as 'iff...(..)'. Right?

Comment: @JaideepKhare Yeah, it's just a one-way implication. In particular, the empty relation is transitive!

Comment: @JaideepKhare: Suppose that we have a relation "contains" and a universe with only two objects in it, a basket with an egg inside it. The basket contains an egg—that is the extent of the relation "contains."  This relation is not reflexive (neither the basket nor the egg contains itself), and not symmetric (the basket contains the egg but the egg doesn't contain the basket), but it *is* transitive, for whenever one thing contains a second thing, and the second thing contains a third thing, the first thing also contains the third thing.

Comment: @BrianTung It is a mystery to me that what do you mean by 'Not quite', btw thanks for your explanation!

Comment: The "whenever" simply isn't triggered because the antecedent never holds.  (The fact that there aren't three things in the universe has a lot to do with that!)  Treating the "whenever" as an iff would not only prevent singleton or empty relations from being transitive, it would require the relation graph to be triangulated, in a way: Any pair $(a, b)$ would have to be accompanied by two other pairs $(a, c)$ and $(c, b)$ (for some other element $c$).

Comment: @JaideepKhare: Sorry, I got rid of it.  I misunderstood one of your later comments.

Comment: @BrianTung I think you should add this as an answer. It fits perfectly fine for an answer.

Comment: @BrianTung "The fact that there aren't three things in the universe has a lot to do with that!" That's misleading - the relation $\{(1, 2), (2, 1)\}$ on $\{1, 2\}$ isn't transitive, so you can still have nontrivial behavior on sets with fewer than three elements. Of course every relation on a one-element set is transitive (and symmetric).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Ahh, you're quite right, thanks for pointing that out.